# Detail Links can´t be found with selenium and bs4?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

i try to find the detail-links from this website:
https://www.kw.com/agent/search/CA/San%20Diego

using the following code:

```py
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

if __name__ == '__main__':
  WAIT = 3  
  print(f"Checking Browser driver...")
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
  srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         
  
  link = f"https://www.kw.com/agent/search/CA/San%20Diego" 
  driver.get (link)        
  time.sleep(WAIT)   
  soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source, 'html.parser')       
  tmpDIV = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "FindAgentRoute__row"})     
  print(f"{len(tmpDIV)} elements found")  
  for elem in tmpDIV:
    print(elem.prettify())
    input("Press!")
```

When i output the elem-information i see this:

```html
   <div class="FindAgentRoute__row">
     <div class="AgentCard">
      <div class="AgentCard__main">
       <div class="AgentCard__avatar Avatar" data-testid="avatar">
        <div class="Avatar__container Avatar__container--highlight Avatar__container--gold Avatar__container--luxury">
         <div class="AvatarImage__bg" style='background-image: url("https://cflare.smarteragent.com/rest/Resizer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.googleapis.com%2Fattachment-prod-e2ad%2Fbp6ub2t9r14crmbc9440&amp;quality=0.8&amp;webp=true&amp;sig_id=69");'>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Avatar__luxury_pill pill">
         luxury agent
        </div>
        <div class="AgentCard__avatarOverlay">
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="AgentCard__content">
        <div class="AgentCard__name AgentCard__row">
         Chris - at Caldwell Group Properties
        </div>
        <div class="AgentCard__languages AgentCard__row">
         English
        </div>
        <div class="AgentCard__location AgentCard__row">
         San Diego, CA
        </div>
        <div>
         <div class="AgentCard__text AgentCard__row">
          License #01937385
         </div>
         <div class="AgentCard__text AgentCard__row">
          Keller Williams Realty
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

So i am not able to see here any a-link with the detail-link for the entry.
When i click on the website on the first entry i get to this detail-page:
https://www.kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385227873501185-2

How can i find the detail-links for the elements?